# UITextView in Swift2.2 shows Pixelated text, how do I regain the lost resolution?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextview, ios9, resolution

[Image of the pixelated text in the UITextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO68G.png)

Does anyone have any suggestions? The image of the issue is in the clickable link above.

Code:

```
struct Views {
    static var name_field: UITextView?
}
```

In the viewDidLoad()

```
    Views.name_field = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, name_field_width, 50))
    Views.name_field!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    Views.name_field!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    Views.name_field!.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
    Views.name_field!.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    Views.name_field!.returnKeyType = .Done
    Views.name_field!.delegate = self
```

Calling this function to style it

`styleIt(Views.name_field!)`

Adds a bottom border style and then sets the font, etc.

```
func styleIt(target: UITextView){
    target.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

    let _border = CAShapeLayer()
    _border.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    _border.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(target.frame) - 1.0, CGRectGetWidth(target.frame), 1.0)

    _border.shadowColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    _border.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
    _border.shadowOpacity = 0.23
    _border.shadowRadius = 4

    target.layer.addSublayer(_border)

    target.font = UIFont(name: "ClementePDaa-Hairline", size: 24)
    target.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    target.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    applyPlaceholderStyle(target, placeholderText: _SEARCH_TEXT)

    target.returnKeyType = .Done
    target.frame = CGRectIntegral(target.frame)

    target.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    _border.shouldRasterize = true
    target.textInputView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
}
```

This UITextView is a subview of `search_field` which is simply a UIView

`search_field!.addSubview(Views.name_field!)`

Comment: Are you using the shouldRasterize option on the layer of the label/textview? Becasue doing this will mess up the contents of UILabels and TextViews.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 I added "textField.shouldRasterize = true" after adding it as a subview to the main view. It doesn't seem to work. Unless do you mean of the actual textfield within the view? Edit: I added "textField.textInputView.layer.shouldRasterize = true", it still doesn't fully regain its full resolution.

Comment: @originaluser2 added the code, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text view is blurry because the frame is using floating numbers.
To force integers value for your frame just do :

`textView.frame = CGRectIntegral(textView.frame)`

Comment: I can only think of this reason as to why a view might appear blurred as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 I added the code, and I did try this option as it did not work though :/

Comment: Instead of targetting `UITextView`, why don't you try targetting your own view which you've created? And remove `target.layer.shouldRasterize = true`.

Comment: oh wow, that worked. Do you know why passing in uitextview, causes the pixelation?

Comment: Because you're not telling your code to target which particular TextView you want.

Comment: So, even though I am passing it in, the code is still confused at it's target/pointer? Hard to grasp, but I think I understand. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I think your code would've worked had you done something like `target = <yourview>` as soon as you open { of your function. Neverthless, happy coding. :)